# quick and dirty SQL string escaping

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, escaping

I'm putting the finishing touches on a home rolled `QueryBuilder` class for a web application with a postgresql DB. It uses `PreparedStatement` for all queries and is protected against SQL injection.

However I wanted a "quick and dirty" way of representing the `QueryBuilder` with its `toString()` method, only for debugging purposes.  The method will assemble the query string as is normally passed into the `PreparedStatement`, then simply replace each `?` in the string with its corresponding single-quoted value. The `toString()` javadoc will warn other devs that it's an unsafe approximation only to be used for debugging, etc etc.

I know the values should have their single quotes doubled up (ie `O'Connell` escapes to `O''Connell`). Are there any other special characters that should be dealt with that I'm forgetting? I looked for similar questions but only found people getting scolded to use `PreparedStatement` (which they should, let the record show).

**EDIT:** not looking to use a third party tool for this particular task, I really just want the quick and dirty here.  I do appreciate the links all the same though - I may consider them for other uses.

**LAST EDIT:** thanks to all for the helpful pointers. I just want to add that for anyone who stumbles in here from google, do *not* use these tricks for anything hitting the database, use `PreparedStatement`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For "quick and dirty" escaping, doubling the apostrophes is good enough. Be aware of question marks already inside string literals, though:

```sql
SELECT column FROM table WHERE column = 'A question?' or column = ?
```

You don't want to replace the first question mark. Also, these corner-cases should be taken care of:

```sql
SELECT /* Is this a comment?? */ * FROM table
-- -- --  Another comment??
WHERE column = ?
```

There's only one bind value in that statement. For a less quick-and-dirty solution, you could use a library like [jOOQ](http://www.jooq.org) for this problem, though (disclaimer: I work for the company behind jOOQ). It'll do the inlining for you, also for the more nasty data types:

```
DSLContext ctx = DSL.using(SQLDialect.POSTGRES);
Object[] bindValues = { 1, "a'bc", Date.valueOf("2012-09-24"), "xy".getBytes() };
String string = ctx.query(
  "SELECT 1 WHERE A = ? AND B = ? AND C = ? AND D = ?",
  bindValues).toString();
```

The above will render

```sql
SELECT 1 
WHERE A = 1 
AND B = 'a''bc'
AND C = date '2012-09-24' 
AND D = E'\\170\\171::bytea
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're not averse to using a 3rd-party open source library, then I'd say take a look at Apache Commons Lang's [StringEscapeUtils.escapeSql(String str)](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html#escapeSql%28java.lang.String%29).

EDIT: I just checked the [source](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/commons/proper/lang/tags/LANG_2_6/src/main/java/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.java?view=markup). It does nothing more than replace a single quote (`'`) with two single quotes (`''`) as you do.

Comment: hmm, that method appears to be doing what I'm doing. The doc also mentions `%` and `_` for `LIKE` clauses, which slipped my mind. this is helpful

Comment: Yup. Edited my answer to say as much. I tend to just use them (commons libs) without bothering to check the source until something breaks. This time, the source doesn't tell us much more than what we already know.

Comment: Notice that the "escapeSql" method has been removed:
http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/article3_0.html

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can give a look at the `escapeJava(String input)` from Apache's [StringEscapeUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringEscapeUtils.html#escapeJava(java.lang.String)).

> public static final String escapeJava(String input)
>
> Escapes the characters in a String using Java String rules.

Comment: thanks, the doc for that method was enough info for me. +1 - hope you don't mind I gave the accept to the new user

Comment: @takacsot: Link should be fixed now.